# alterar class do elemento clicado

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, lista

então galera eu tenho uma lista:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
   <li class="active"><a href="#novas"><span class="badge badge-info"><?php echo $qtd_novas ?></span> Novas Mensagens</a></li>
   <li><a href="#andamento">Em Andamento</a></li>
   <li><a href="#resolvidas">Resolvidas</a></li>
   <li><a href="#canceladas">Canceladas</a></li>
   <li><a href="#pendentes">Pendentes</a></li>
</ul>
```

a primeira linha possui uma `class="active"` que seta a tab que será mostrada primeiro, bom minha dúvida é a seguinte, como eu crio uma função no javascript para sempre guardar a ultima tab clicada, pois eu quero que quando o usuário saia da página e depois volte para a mesma a última tab que ele clicou seja mostrada primeiro

Comment: Se não for *single page* você terá que usar alguma forma de armazenar essa última *tab* clicada no cliente. Por exemplo, com `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage`.

Comment: como assim _single page_? Acho que estou interpretando errado sua resposta kkk

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo usando `localstorage`, que nada mais é que um armazém local de chave/valor que persiste além do fechamento da aba/browser.

A única coisa que tive de fazer é armazenar o ID do último elemento clicado, e refazer o clique no elemento usando `trigger` do jQuery no próximo carregamento da página, lendo o ID previamente armazenado. Mas pode ser outra forma sem jQuery, o importante é smular o clique de alguma forma.

**Exemplo funcional**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs > li").click(function() {
                $(this).siblings().removeClass("ativo");
                $(this).addClass("ativo");
                localStorage.setItem("ultimo", $(this).attr("id"));
            });

            var ultimo = localStorage.getItem("ultimo");
            if (ultimo)
                $("#" + ultimo).click();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        li {
            background-color: #FFF;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        li.ativo {
            background-color: #DDF;
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li id="tabA">A</li>
        <li id="tabB">B</li>
        <li id="tabC">C</li>
        <li id="tabD">D</li>
    <ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no caso de uma `ul li` utilizo `$("$nome_id ul li").click(function() {})` ?

Comment: Fiz uma alteração para mostrar como fica com `ul` e `li`.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que este trecho de código de exemplo atenderá sua necessidade. Principalmente pelo fato deste código considerar o caso em que o usuário vem de qualquer link que aponte para a "tab" desejada.

Optei por escrever código JS nativo, mas você também poderá simplificá-lo com jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #myTab > li.active {
   background: #808080; /* Exemplo */
  }
 </style>

 <script>
  var hashchange_handler = function () {
   var hash = window.location.hash;

   /* É interessante que neste ponto sejam filtrados os valores válidos */

   var myTabs = document.getElementById('myTab');

   var active;
   while(active = myTab.querySelector('#myTab > li.active'))
    active.classList.remove("active");
   
   active = myTab.querySelector('#myTab > li > a[href="' + hash + '"]')
   active.parentNode.classList.add("active");
  }

  if(window.location.hash)
   window.addEventListener("load", hashchange_handler)
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashchange_handler);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#novas"><span class="badge badge-info"><?php echo $qtd_novas ?></span> Novas Mensagens</a></li>
  <li><a href="#andamento">Em Andamento</a></li>
  <li><a href="#resolvidas">Resolvidas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#canceladas">Canceladas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pendentes">Pendentes</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução pode passar pelo uso da propriedade `cookie`:

## [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

> Obter e definir os biscoitos associados ao documento atual.

As especificações pode ser lidas em: [DOM Level 2: HTMLDocument.cookie](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-8747038)

## Compatibilidade

A solução em baixo apresentada só precisa de suporte básico (ler, escrever), e em termos de compatibilidade [podemos observar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Browser_compatibility) que a solução funciona virtualmente em qualquer navegador:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                           Suporte em Desktop                           │
├────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────┬─────────────────┤
│ Chrome │ Firefox (Gecko) │ Internet Explorer │ Opera │ Safari (WebKit) │
├────────┼─────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────┼─────────────────┤
│ Sim    │ Sim             │ Sim               │ Sim   │ Sim             │
└────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────┘

┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                              Suporte em Mobile                             │
├─────────┬────────────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┤
│ Android │ Firefox Mobile (Gecko) │ IE Phone │ Opera Mobile │ Safari Mobile │
├─────────┼────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┤
│ Sim     │ Sim                    │ Sim      │ Sim          │ Sim           │
└─────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

## Código

A parte relevante está no JavaScript, onde vamos proceder à leitura e à escrita do *cookie* para podermos carregar o separador correto quando o visitante volta:

```
/* document.cookie devolve todos os cookies acessíveis pelo presente documento.
 * Tão cedo quanto possível, realizamos uma filtragem para ficar apenas
 * com o valor do cookie que nos interessa.
 */
$(function(){
    var ultimaTab = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)tabAtiva\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
    $('a[href="'+ultimaTab+'"').trigger("click");
});

/* Twitter Bootstrap tem eventos associados às tabs, pelo que podemos fazer uso
 * dos mesmos para que ao ser apresentada uma nova tab, estejamos também a guardar
 * a sua identificação no nosso cookie.
 */    
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    document.cookie = "tabAtiva="+tab+"; expires=Fri, 28 Dec 2040 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
});
```

## Exemplo

O presente exemplo encontra-se também disponível no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/448ezty4/) onde podemos aceder ao mesmo, mudar de tab, fechar o separador do navegador, voltar a aceder ao JSFiddle e comprovar que a tab aberta na altura em que fechamos o separador é efetivamente a que se encontra aberta quando voltamos ao JSFiddle.

```js
$(function(){
    var ultimaTab = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)tabAtiva\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
    $('a[href="'+ultimaTab+'"').trigger("click");
});

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    document.cookie = "tabAtiva="+tab+"; expires=Fri, 28 Dec 2040 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
});
```

```css
body{
    padding:10px;
    font-size:9px;
}
.tab-content{
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#novas" aria-controls="novas" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Novas Mensagens</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#andamento" aria-controls="andamento" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Em Andamento</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#resolvidas" aria-controls="resolvidas" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Resolvidas</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#canceladas" aria-controls="canceladas" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Canceladas</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#pendentes" aria-controls="pendents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pendentes</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="novas">
        A minha tab com as novas entradas
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="andamento">
        Assuntos em andamento
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="resolvidas">
        Cenas resolvidas
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="pendentes">
        Cenas pendentes
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="canceladas">
        Cenas canceladas
    </div>
</div>
```

<sup>No exemplo usando o *snippet* da SE, o exemplo falha devido à forma como é carregado o mesmo.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Enquanto eu desenvolvia minha outra solução, [o usuário Miguel Angelo postou uma outra solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57914/129) que atende ao caso. Aproveito para postar uma solução contendo tanto a minha proposta quanto a dele já que temos benefícios em ambos casos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #myTab > li.active {
   background: #808080; /* Exemplo */
  }
 </style>

 <script>
  var hashchange_handler = function () {
   
   // Identifica o hash-part do endereço
   var hash = window.location.hash; 

   // Se a hash-part não tiver sido definido no endereço,
   // Exibe o último tab visitado.
   if (!hash && localStorage)
    hash = localStorage.getItem("ultimo"); // Miguel Angelo
   
   // Caso não especificarmos o tab a ser exibido no endereço,
   // e o usuário não tiver um último visitado, elegemos um padrão
   if (!hash)
    hash = '#novas'; // Default

   /* É interessante que neste ponto sejam filtrados os valores válidos */

   var myTabs = document.getElementById('myTab');

   var active;
   while(active = myTab.querySelector('#myTab > li.active'))
    active.classList.remove("active");
   
   active = myTab.querySelector('#myTab > li > a[href="' + hash + '"]')
   active.parentNode.classList.add("active");

   if(localStorage)
    localStorage.setItem("ultimo", hash); // Miguel Angelo
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", hashchange_handler)
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashchange_handler);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#novas"><span class="badge badge-info"><?php echo $qtd_novas ?></span> Novas Mensagens</a></li>
  <li><a href="#andamento">Em Andamento</a></li>
  <li><a href="#resolvidas">Resolvidas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#canceladas">Canceladas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pendentes">Pendentes</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quando eu altero a `li` clicada (testei clicando na terceira, **`Resolvidas`**) e recarrego a página, o `active` volta para a primeira `li` **`Novas Mensagens`** (FF 37).

Comment: Renan, creio que a página não esteja disparando o evento "load" corretamente, qual navegador você usa?